# Parsing complex json object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

i have this scenario of having a mixed response from a server and i need to process its data in PHP

```
Array
(
    [14424174] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 45
                    [nm] => This is a driver name
                    [ph] => 5454545
                )

        )

)
```

I want to access id, nm, ph values

but i had no luck cause this index number (14424174) is unknown to me, so i need to first store this index and then parse the array

Comment: You can use `array_unshift()` to pull the first element off the front of an array. (Or `array_pop()` to pull the last element off the end, which is the same if the array has only one thing in it.)

Comment: Or use http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php, if the structure shown is the complete one.

Comment: You can also use `$array[key($array)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested `foreach()`:

```
foreach($arr as $i => $sub_arr)
{
   foreach($sub_arr as $sub_i => $sub_sub_arr)
   {
      $id = $sub_sub_arr['id'];
      $nm = $sub_sub_arr['nm'];
      $ph = $sub_sub_arr['ph'];
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! that worked , you made my day !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following pattern:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$val) {
   //get the id:
   var_dump($key)//14424174
   $nm = $val[nm];
   $ph = $val[ph];
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! i was able to get the index value ! much appreciated